# Why does my request for a partial, using :remote isn't working?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, cancan

I'm creating a simple Rails App, to work as a base app for my projects, and in the user edit profile page I cannot be able to load a partial via asynchronous requests.

Here is my base view for a edit profile page:

**app/views/users/edit.html.haml**

```
container-fluid
  .row-fluid
    .span3
      .well
        %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
          %li.nav-header Profile
          %li
            = link_to 'Personal Infos', 'settings', remote: true
```

My settings action on the controller:

**app/controllers/users_controller.erb**

```
...

def settings
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

...
```

**app/views/users/settings.js.erb**

```
$('div#settings_body').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('edit_profile'))%>")
```

And finally, my partial:

**app/views/users/_edit_profile.html.haml**

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.submit "Save"
```

But when I click on the link "Personal Infos" nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was struggling for three days with this problem and - don't ask me why - I removed the `remote: true` command from the link to see what happens. When I clicked on the link then, my app caught and authorization problem.

I'm using CanCan to handle authorization in this app and that was my ability file:

**app/models/ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(User)
     can [:read, :edit], User, :id => resource.id
    end
  end

end
```

The problem is that I added a new action *settings* to the user controller, CanCan was blocking the controller to run this action, and the partial wasn't being loaded.

I changed my ability file as follows:

**app/models/ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(User)
     can [:read, :edit, :settings], User, :id => resource.id
    end
  end

end
```

And it worked.

Comment: You've could try to debug your responses with e.g. firebug, that may save you some time ;)

Comment: Great! Can you answer that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682883/my-partial-wasnt-loading-because-of-cancan-authorization-how-can-i-debug-that) I created about how to debut this?