# My partial wasn't loading because of CanCan authorization. How can I debug that?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, partial-views, cancan

I was having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682411/why-does-my-request-for-a-partial-using-remote-isnt-working/15682412#15682412) problem trying to render a partial via an asynchronous request from my users views.

The problem was that CanCan was not authorizing the call, because it was inside a new action that I created on *user_controller.rb*. I am new to Rails and I thought that putting `:edit` on the ability class was enough.

I caught this error because I removed the `remote: true` from my link, so it can render the view via a http request. Don't as me why I did that. Begginer's luck!

My question is: how could I have debugged that error if not by luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have added test cases that accounted for the rendering of that partial, for instance (with rspec):

```
response.should render_template(:partial => 'partial_name')
```

Comment: But this would have shown me that the error was happening because the authorization or just that the error was happening?

Comment: That would have raised the `flag` that something was wrong with the rendering of the partial. You build upon that (incrementally) to figure out the why. That perhaps combined with how CanCan do its own testing could lead somewhere: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/spec/cancan/ability_spec.rb#L6